# Trying to re-use layouts with minor differences programmatically

Tags: java, android

I currently have a layout consisting of 1 image view and 2 text views. I'm trying to make it so that the user can input a picture and their own name of a restaurant and their own rating of a restaurant, so essentially they need to be able to add two text views and an image view, but the overall layout will remain consistent. Is there any way to use the  tag programmatically with minor differences based off of the user input? Thanks!

Comment: Can you resuse a layout?  yes you just set the text/image programatically at runtime.  Beyond that I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @GabeSechan So how would I create a new instance of each view based off the user input, and then combining that into a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a list of repeating views, you can check ListView. With it, you can achieve a layout such as

[image: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/ListView/]

With this, you can define one layout that repeats several times inside your parent layout (ListView).

For a complete guide, please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview).

Comment: how would i programatically add more views?

Comment: In the link, it discusses about the listview and adapter working together to populate your list with data using one layout.